# Opencart 301 редирект

Tags: .htaccess, opencart, redirect

Задача такая: есть два сайта, два домена, например: site.ru и old-site.ru. Один из сайтов находился на site.ru, его я перенес на old-site.ru, а на первый домен поставил второй сайт. Но теперь мне нужно, чтобы все старые ссылки улетали с site.ru на old-site.ru посредством редиректа 301, но при этом не затрагивались новые. Оба сайта на опенкарте. Вот что я прописал в htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/catalog/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://old-site.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Но это не срабатывает, я также пробовал использовать карманы в самом `RewriteCond`, затем подставлять их в `RewriteRule`, но безуспешно, подскажите пожалуйста, что может быть не так?

Comment: apache вообще используется га сервере?

Comment: Как вы собрались определять какие ссылки новые, а какие старые ?